# Parse.Object.destroyAll() not working today

Tags: parse-platform

Parse.Object.destroyAll() not working today.

It used to work yesterday and before, but since today destroyAll is not working.
I am using cloud code and trying to delete some objects using destroyAll.
The success and failure functions are not called, and also the objects are not deleted from the parse database.

Anyone else seeing such issues ?